# Android M: Application does not require any special access?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, installation, permissions

I have a question with Runtime Permission Model on Android M. My app requires Location and External Storage permission.
The above permissions are supposed to be requested from the user as required i.e. just before the code which required these permissions.

Now, when the app is installed, I get a screen that says "[App] does not require any special access".

[image]

Is it the correct behavior?

Comment: Yes, because your permissions are requested during code execution of a certain app feature. Right?

Comment: @AaronGillion Yes , maybe you're right . Do you have any idea what does special access mean here ? Will it be the case when I ask permissions upfront before letting user use the app ?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Your app is asking for permission which may hurt/affect the user, but also it does not mean that your user will not be able to execute your app if he/she does not allow permission and also if you code it properly. And it is also the reason why it is not listed while installing the app, you will need explicitly handle that stuff.